# Error C2676; Having trouble defining the ++ operator in a Binary Search Tree class in C++

Tags: c++, iterator, binary-search-tree

I have an Iterator class that defines the ++ operator:

```
template<typename T>
class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T>
{
public:
    Iterator(TreeNode<T>* p)
    {
        if (p == nullptr)
            current = -1; // The end
        else
        {
            // Get all the elements in inorder
            treeToVector(p);
            current = 0;
        }
    }

    Iterator operator++()
    {
        current++;
        if (current == v.size())
            current = -1; // The end
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        return v[current];
    }
    bool operator==(const Iterator<T>& iterator) const
    {
        return current == iterator.current;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Iterator<T>& iterator) const
    {
        return current != iterator.current;
    }

private: int current;
         vector<T> v;
         void treeToVector(TreeNode<T>* p)
         {
             if (p != nullptr)
             {
                 treeToVector(p->left);
                 v.push_back(p->element);
                 treeToVector(p->right);
             }
         }
};
```

I have a TestBSTIterator file to make sure it works:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include "BST.h"

using namespace std;

string toUpperCase(string& s)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a binary search tree for strings
    BST<string> tree;

    // Add elements to the tree
    tree.insert("America");
    tree.insert("Canada");
    tree.insert("Russia");
    tree.insert("France");

    // Traverse a binary tree using iterators
    for (Iterator<string> iterator = tree.begin();
        iterator != tree.end(); iterator++)
    {
        cout << toUpperCase(*iterator) << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << "Min element is " <<
        *min_element(tree.begin(), tree.end()) << endl;

    cout << "Max element is "
        << *max_element(tree.begin(), tree.end()) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run TestBSTIterator I get the following error:

error C2676: binary '++': 'Iterator' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

1> with

1> [

1>       T=std::string

1> ]

I have the "operator ++" function in the Iterator class, so I don't really understand what the problem is. I tried simply implementing the function with a generic type, i.e. Iterator operator++() { ... } but that had no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `Iterator operator++()`, which is the *prefix* operator (`++iterator`), but you use `iterator++`, the *postfix* operator, which is defined with `Iterator operator++(int)`.  The int is typically unused, and is used solely to differentiate between the two increment operators.

Either use `++iterator` in your code, or define the postfix operator.